# Elastic grid jquery not working right in firefox

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

[Elastic grid jquery](https://github.com/vukhanhtruong/jquery-elastic-grid) doesn't work with fullpage.js in firefox but it's works fine with chrome.

see - http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you read the [fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions).

It is very probably that you are not initializing it in the `afterRender` callback of fullPage.js.